# htaccess redirect subdomain with www to non www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a subdomain with www to the subdomain.

So for example:

https://www.blog.example.com

to

https://blog.example.com

How can I achieve that?

I already tried this, but that does not work:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_?

Comment: Is the interpretation of dynamic configuration files enabled at all? Is the rewriting module loaded at all? Anything in your http servers error log file?

Comment: @arkascha Thanks! Yes the rewriting module is loaded. But when I check it by loading the page including www. it does not redirect it to the page without www.

Comment: And the other questions I asked?

Comment: Also the `RewriteEngine on` is missing in your code above.

Comment: Also take care that you are not looking at a client side cached result. Clear or disable your browsers cache or make a "deep reload".